# generic class and generic method , what would be the reason to define the class a generic class in the below example

Tags: c#, generics

Is there any difference between the two. What would be the reason that I define a generic class of type T.

If I just define the methods does it mean the same as defining the class of Type T.

```
void Main()
{
    Test1<int> x = new Test1<int>();
    x.Test1Method(1);

    Test2 x1 = new Test2();
    x1.Test2Method(1);
}

public class Test1<T>
{
    public void Test1Method<T>(T x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}

public class Test2
{
    public void Test2Method<T>(T x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `Test1` have any other methods? The type parameter to `Test1Method` is shadowing the type parameter for the class.

Comment: Your `Test1` class should be giving you compiler warnings about using the same name for a generic parameter as one that has already been defined.

Comment: I see your guys point but then if I just define the class with Type T I can pretty much do everything I can do [if I had defined the generic methods], when would I go for generic class vs generic method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the same, but the difference is only evident when you have properties/fields with a generic type (which you can only do when the class itself is generic) or you have multiple methods:

```
public class ArrayWrapper<T> {
    private T[] elements;

    public T get(int index) {
        return elements[index];
    }

    public void set(int index, T value) {
        elements[index] = value;
    }
}
```

Without `<T>` on the class, the `T[] elements` field will not compile, and it would be possible to use different types in `get()` and `set()` on the same object.

(As Lee pointed out, you probably don't want to use `<T>` on the methods when you have it on the class, as having it in both places would actually introduce another generic type parameter for the method which is independent of the one for the class...)

Comment: I see your point but then if I just define the class with Type T I can pretty much do everything I can do [if I had defined the generic methods],  when would I go for generic class vs generic method.

Comment: It depends on whether you want/need the types of the methods to be tied together, and if you want/need a generic field or property. In my example, these were both necessary, but in other situations, you might instead need methods with independent types (this is less common, though, and happens more often with classes containing static utility methods).

Answer (score 2):

In class `Test1`, the `T` that is defined on the class level is different from the `T` defined on the `Test1Method` method. This makes the `T` on the class level useless.

You could use `Test1` like this:

```
Test1<string> x = new Test1<string>();
x.Test1Method(1);
```

In this case the first `T` is `string` and the second `T` is int.

As it is right now, `Test1` is no different than `Test2`.

It would have been different if you defined `Test1` like this:

```
public class Test1<T>
{
    public void Test1Method(T x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

Notice after this change how `Test1Method` does not have a generic `T` parameter. Now this class is different from `Test2` in that in `Test1` you specify `T` upon object construction, and in `Test2` you can have a different `T` everytime you invoke `Test2Method`.

Here is an example of how you can use the two classes (after the change I introduced):

```
Test1<int> x = new Test1<int>();
x.Test1Method(1); //valid
x.Test1Method(2); //valid
x.Test1Method("str"); //invalid

Test2 x1 = new Test2();
x1.Test2Method(1); //valid
x1.Test2Method("str"); //valid
```